# SBS2011 (Windows Server 2008 r2) Correct way to Schedule reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, windows-sbs-2011

I'm after the correct way to schedule a reboot on an SBS2011/WS2008r2 box.

External support company created a `reboot.bat` file and added a scheduled task to run it at 6am every Monday morning.

`reboot.bat` contains:

```
shutdown -r -f
```

The batch executes correctly and reboots the server cleanly, yet upon reboot the Server is left with the following screen:

[image]

What is the best way to schedule this reboot?

This reboot is to solve performance problems due to running database reports on a Sunday afternoon. I am fully aware about the problems we have by running additional databases on an SBS box (if it were my choice we wouldn't be).

Similar questions, but none answer the Event Tracker problem: [1](https://serverfault.com/q/1717/106401), [2](https://serverfault.com/q/401392/106401), [3](https://serverfault.com/q/314311/106401).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide the `/d` option to give a reason for the shutdown in advance.

You can get a list of the reasons available to you by running `shutdown /?` in a terminal.  However, given your scenario I'd use `shutdown /r /f /d p:4:1` for "Application maintenance (Planned)".

Comment: Excellent thanks Falcon, have made the change but will have to wait until next Monday morning to check it's success!

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that arguments in a batch file have to be used with a dash `-` rather than a backslash `/` ?

Comment: `/` is a forward slash and is the traditional way of specifying arguments to windows command line programs.  It should work regardless of context.  Most things support `-` as well and in the case of this utility I believe they are completely interchangeable.

Comment: Ok thanks, tested here successfully, but not on a WS2008 machine (thankfully don't have any of them here!) ;)